# ShareCompat.IntentBuilder: Intent.data mixed with recipient

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` in order to send an email with an attached file.

I have no issue with the attached file except that the uri of the file I want to attach is automatically added to the recipient.

See by yourself:

[image]

Here is the code I use to send the email:

```
val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".fileprovider", pdfFile)
val shareIntentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
    .from(this@MyActivity)
    .setType(baseContext.contentResolver.getType(fileUri))
    .setStream(fileUri)
    .setSubject(getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setText("Please find attached ...")
    .setEmailTo(arrayOf("email@gmail.com"))

val shareIntent = shareIntentBuilder.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
shareIntent.data = fileUri
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

(I have used this tutorial: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b)

Does one of you know what mistake I have done?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `shareIntent.data = fileUri` was the problem. Everything works fine when I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late for answer.

> [**`setData()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setData(android.net.Uri)) - This method ***automatically clears any type*** that was previously set by
>   `setType(String)` or `setTypeAndNormalize(String)`

If you saw the Notes from [the medium link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b), they never used `setType()` and `setData()` at the same time;

> **Note:** we don’t call `setType()` anywhere when building our `ShareCompat`
>   (even though in the video I did set it). As explained in the
>   `setDataAndType()` Javadoc, ***the type is automatically inferred from the
>   data URI*** using `getContentResolver().getType(uriToImage)`. ***Since
>   `FileProvider` returns the correct mime type automatically***, *we don’t
>   need to manually specify a mime type at all*.

So using `setData()` is unnecessary since the documentation also said:

> `Uri`: The `Uri` of the data this intent is now targeting. ***This value may
>   be null***.

---

Also, you already set and get the `type` by `setType` & `getType(fileUri)` and you won't need to set that again. However, to simplify your codes, you can try using this:

```
val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".fileprovider", pdfFile)
val shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                .from(this@MainActivity)
                .setType(baseContext.contentResolver.getType(fileUri))
                .setStream(fileUri)
                .setSubject(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setText("Please find attached ...")
                .setEmailTo(arrayOf("email@gmail.com"))
                .intent // added this
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

Good samples [are here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat).